# get_object_or_404 Nameerror

Tags: python, django, pdb

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect, render
from .models import Post, Comment ,Question , Call , Upload ,call_Comment , question_Comment , Search , Font
from .forms import CommentForm, PostForm , CallForm, QuestionForm , UploadForm , QuestionCommentForm , CallCommentForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from .extracting_existing_fonts import estand, eflatten, econversion
from .font_similarity  import stand, flatten, conversion, jacsim




def index(request):
    post_list = Post.objects.all()
    question_list = Question.objects.all()
    call_list = Call.objects.all()
    search_list = Search.objects.all()
    upload_list = Upload.objects.all()

    #Search function
    query = request.GET.get("q")
    if query:
        search_list = search_list.filter(title__icontains=query)


    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {
        'post_list' : post_list,
        'question_list':question_list,
        'call_list':call_list,
        'search_list':search_list,
        'upload_list':upload_list,

    })

def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {
            'post' : post,
        })

def question_detail(request, pk):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'blog/question_detail.html', {
            'question' : question,
        })

def call_detail(request, pk):
    call = get_object_or_404(Call, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'blog/call_detail.html', {
            'call' : call,
        })


def upload_detail(request, pk):
    import pdb
    pdb.set_trace()

    upload = get_object_or_404(Upload, pk=pk)
    """
    efont = get_object_or_404(Font, pk=pk)
    upload_font = conversion(upload.photo.path)
    stored_font = []
    for etitle, efontfile in efont:
        stored_font.append({etitle : jacsim(upload_font, econversion(efontfile.path))})
    """
    return render(request, 'blog/upload_detail.html', {
            'upload' : upload, 

    })


@login_required
def post_new(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form = form.save(commit=False)
            form.save()
            return redirect('blog:post_detail' , form.pk)
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, "blog/post_form.html",{
        "form":form,
        })


@login_required
def comment_new(request, post_pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk = post_pk)

    if request.method =='POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.author = request.user
            comment.save()
            return redirect('blog:post_detail', post.pk)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/comment_form.html', {
            'form':form,
        })

@login_required
def comment_edit(request, post_pk, pk):
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, pk=pk)
    if comment.author != request.user:
        return redirect('blog:post_detail', post_pk)

    if request.method =='POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=comment)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save()
            return redirect('blog:post_detail', post_pk)
    else:
        form = CommentForm(instance=comment)
    return render(request, 'blog/comment_form.html', {
            'form':form,
        })

@login_required
def comment_delete(request, post_pk, pk):
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, pk=pk)
    if comment.author != request.user:
        return redirect('blog:post_detail', post_pk)

    if request.method =='POST':
        comment.delete()
        return redirect('blog:post_detail', post_pk)

    return render(request, 'blog/comment_confirm_delete.html', {
            'comment': comment,
    })



@login_required
def question_new(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        form = QuestionForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form = form.save(commit=False)
            form.save()
            return redirect('blog:question_detail' , form.pk)
    else:
        form = QuestionForm()
    return render(request, "blog/question_form.html",{
        "form":form,
        })

@login_required
def question_comment_new(request, question_pk):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk = question_pk)

    if request.method =='POST':
        form = QuestionCommentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            question_comment = form.save(commit=False)
            question_comment.question = question
            question_comment.author = request.user
            question_comment.save()
            return redirect('blog:question_detail', question.pk)
    else:
        form = QuestionCommentForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/question_comment_form.html', {
            'form':form,
        })


@login_required
def question_comment_edit(request, question_pk, pk):
    question_comment= get_object_or_404(question_Comment, pk=pk)
    if question_comment.author != request.user:
        return redirect('blog:question_detail', question_pk)

    if request.method =='POST':
        form = QuestionCommentForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=question_comment)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save()
            return redirect('blog:question_detail', question_pk)
    else:
        form = QuestionCommentForm(instance=question_comment)
    return render(request, 'blog/question_comment_form.html', {
            'form':form,
        })

@login_required
def question_comment_delete(request, question_pk, pk):
    question_comment = get_object_or_404(question_Comment, pk=pk)
    if question_comment.author != request.user:
        return redirect('blog:question_detail', question_pk)

    if request.method =='POST':
        question_comment.delete()
        return redirect('blog:question_detail', question_pk)

    return render(request, 'blog/comment_confirm_delete.html', {
            'question_comment': question_comment,
    })

@login_required
def call_new(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        form = CallForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form = form.save(commit=False)
            form.save()
            return redirect('blog:call_detail' , form.pk)
    else:
        form = CallForm()
    return render(request, "blog/call_form.html",{
        "form":form,
        })

@login_required
def call_comment_new(request, call_pk):
    call = get_object_or_404(Call, pk = call_pk)

    if request.method =='POST':
        form = CallCommentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            call_comment = form.save(commit=False)
            call_comment.call = call
            call_comment.author = request.user
            call_comment.save()
            return redirect('blog:call_detail', call.pk)
    else:
        form = CallCommentForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/call_comment_form.html', {
            'form':form,
        })


@login_required
def call_comment_edit(request, call_pk, pk):
    call_comment = get_object_or_404(call_Comment, pk=pk)
    if call_comment.author != request.user:
        return redirect('blog:call_detail',call_pk)

    if request.method =='POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=call_comment)
        if form.is_valid():
            call_comment = form.save()
            return redirect('blog:call_detail',call_pk)
    else:
        form = CommentForm(instance=call_comment)
    return render(request, 'blog/comment_form.html', {
            'form':form,
        })

@login_required
def call_comment_delete(request, call_pk, pk):
    call_comment = get_object_or_404(call_Comment, pk=pk)
    if call_comment.author != request.user:
        return redirect('blog:call_detail',call_pk)

    if request.method =='POST':
        call_comment.delete()
        return redirect('blog:call_detail',call_pk)

    return render(request, 'blog/comment_confirm_delete.html', {
            'call_comment': call_comment,
    })

@login_required
def upload_new(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        form = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form = form.save(commit=False)
            form.save()
            return redirect('blog:upload_detail', form.pk)
    else:
        form = UploadForm()
    return render(request, "blog/upload_form.html",{
        "form":form,
        })



#파일 업로드

# Create your views here.
```

My code has an error Nameerror: name 'upload' is not defined
However, I have already imported all the models and also imported get_object_or_404 from django.shortcuts as you can see on my code above.
What's the cause of error? I donna what is wrong

Comment: please post full traceback

Comment: Post the full stacktrace

Comment: Perhaps you have to restart your server, so that the current code that contains the import is loaded.

Comment: Too much code, too few error message.